# How to change the hyper link base on current link

Tags: php, jquery

This is a header row of my result table. I would like to make the **Title** link to set sorting order, when it is order=asc currently, it should produce a link order=desc and vice versa.

The php query codes  I has built.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><a class="sorting" href="?orderby=title&order=asc">Title</a></td>
<td>Catagory</td>
<td>Tags</td>
<td>Comments</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP or jQuery here. If you haven't tried anything that may have failed, then this is a code request and shows no effort on your part. **Too broad**.

Comment: You do not have jquery or php, why tag them?

Comment: Given what the `href` looks like, this sounds a lot like you want to use this in conjunction with a DB, which is another reason I'm not touching this one. ***Too too broad & unclear***.

Comment: He says that he has created a query string to pass in the url that he is going to use in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery check url ,and set it accordingly href

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("order=asc") > -1) {
   $(".sorting").attr('href','?orderby=title&order=desc')
}
```

Comment: assumes that link isn't used for ajax and how does it work for reverse?

Comment: Where op specified ajax ??

Comment: they didn't , am just pointing it out. OP doesn't provide much detail at all and thus it's not always best to guess at answers

Answer (score 0):

Using *jQuery*:

```js
$(".sorting").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ($(".sorting").attr('href') == "?orderby=title&order=asc") ? $(".sorting").attr("href", "?orderby=title&order=desc") : $(".sorting").attr("href", "?orderby=title&order=asc");
    console.log($(this).prop("href"));
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td><a class="sorting" href="?orderby=title&order=asc">Title</a>

        </td>
        <td>Catagory</td>
        <td>Tags</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See your console(Ctrl + Shift+ I in Chrome) for your confirmation.

Comment: I change to window.location.href = $(this).prop("href"); But it can not toggle the change. But the log is work

Comment: @Steven I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/0g43g72u/

```js
$('table').find('a.sorting').click(function() {
  var k = $(this).attr("href");
  var newk = "";
  if (k.indexOf("asc") >= 0) {
    newk = k.replace("asc", "desc")
    $(this).attr("href", newk);
  } else if (k.indexOf("desc") >= 0) {
    newk = k.replace("desc", "asc");
    $(this).attr("href", newk);
  }
  alert("New href attached to the link is -> "+newk);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><a class="sorting" href="?orderby=title&order=asc">Title</a>

    </td>
    <td>Catagory</td>
    <td>Tags</td>
    <td>Comments</td>
    <td>Date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```